# f:param return null when rendered

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have this code inside dataGrid. When this is rendered f:param return null. If I click on `p:selectBooleanCheckbox` f:param return the correct ID of particular item in the grid. How can I force f:param to return correct ID when rendered. I need to achieve this: I show user multiple items in dataGrid. I use pagging as well. I want user to be able to select multiple items for comparison table. This all works. The problem is when user goes back and forward in datagrid. `p:selectBooleanCheckbox` is always unchecked even though user selected this before

```
<p:selectBooleanCheckbox itemLabel="Compare" value="#{compare.checkCompare}">
<f:param name = "id2" value="#{camp.campID}" />
<p:ajax listener="#{compare.compare()}" />
</p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
```

Comment: [mcve] please... always... and version info

Comment: value has to be a boolean. checkCompare looks like a function? Who will use `id2`?